# Frame Size Properties Are Returning Zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working with a couple of different views, one is an image view and the other is a label.  I have to use the frame size values (width and height) in code, but they are returning values of zero.  When I look at the settings in my storyboard, this is clearly not the case, but when I log the values to the console, they are zero.  Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your outlets aren't connected. Please include relevant code, however.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout? If so, you are probably checking the frames too early, before layout is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Either your outlets are not connected, or you views have not been instantiated yet because you are too early in the view life cycle. Try your log statements in `viewDidLoad` and in `viewDidAppear` and compare.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a frame and bounds is that the frame is expressed in superview's coordinates. Since you just need the size, if the view hasn't a superview, you shouldn't consider it's frame, rather the bounds:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGRect bounds;
```

Reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: Every visible view (that's not a window) has a superview.

Comment: I assumed it's not visible, implied it from the fact that it hasn't a superview.

Comment: The views are in an xib. They have superviews.